# How do I refocus a <TextInput> after an event?

Tags: android, react-native, input, text, focus

When the screen loads, I use the following code to focus on a :

```
useEffect(() => {
  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    if (refText.current) {
      refText.current.focus();
    }
  });
}, []);
```

This works as expected. However, on a submit event, the  needs focus again.

```
function myEvent() {
  if (refText.current) {
    refText.current.focus();
  }
}
```

This does not focus on the text again. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try to wrap it with a setTimer of let's say 10ms?

Comment: Hi @YaNuSH, I already tried it without luck :)

Comment: Could you please add the part from where the "myEvent" method is called? Better, if you post the minimal code to reproduce the issue or all the content of the file if it's small.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the current code that you have posted. if you can provide a git link with the code that can simulate the same behaviour that you are experiencing right now, people can give it a try

Comment: It worked indeed, commenting out all other code. It ended up being a simple spinner code that prevented it from working. I swapped it for another and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i don't know why you'd need a `if` statement inside your submit handler to set the focus on the `TextInput`, but anyways, I presume you have a event handler on your `Button` declaration. E.g:

```js
function App() {
  const textRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (textRef.current) textRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput placeholder="Input" ref={textRef}/>
      <Button title="Submit" onPress={handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
}
});
```

It works fine as you can see in this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-feather-lx5bi?file=/src/App.js:108-572).

Comment: Thank you for you effort! It worked indeed, commenting out all other code. It ended up being a simple spinner code that prevented it from working. I swapped it for another and it worked!